# Apache Derby: Create SQL Dump with data

Tags: java, derby

is there any easy way to create a complete SQL Dump from an apache Derby DB? 
Using the dblook tool, I managed to dump the database schema to a sql file, however there seems to be no way to get the data included.

Comment: You're really looking for an administration tool - you might have better luck on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 7):

Derby has procedures for bulk import/export. Here's an example of using the `ij` tool to export the `APP.MESSAGES` table:

```
>ij
ij version 10.3
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:dbName';
ij> CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE('APP', 'MESSAGES',
                                  'myfile.del', null, null, 'UTF-8');
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
```

See the [Derby Tools and Utilities Guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/manuals/index.html) for your version.

This is not in the format you're asking for. Beyond that, you may need to resort to external tools.

Answer (score 0):

SquirrelSQL can create INSERT statements for your data. Would that work for you? I Don't know whether a library exists to do the same from within your application,

Answer (score 0):

This unix shell script dumps the data of all tables in APP database, to ~/tmp/export/[TABLE].del files. The assumption here is that the database is in folder "db" in the current working directory and that derby is installed under ~/derby. So you see, it's pretty custom (built for my own specific needs) but easily adjustable. And no, it does NOT make SQL dumps, they will all be in derby CSV export format. However, you can use this format to import data into [PostgreSQL with the COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html) statement, or into [MySQL with LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html). Hope this helps.

UPD: I put my derby scripts together in a [docker image](https://cloud.docker.com/repository/registry-1.docker.io/crocodile2u/derby-dumper), enjoy! It has SQL dumps ;-)

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/derby/bin
DIR="$HOME/tmp/export"

printf "connect 'jdbc:derby:db';\nshow tables in APP;" > show.sql

TABLES=$(ij show.sql | grep ^APP | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/|//g')

echo $TABLES
for TABLE in $TABLES;
do      
        echo $TABLE
        printf "connect 'jdbc:derby:db';\nCALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE (null,'$TABLE','$DIR/$TABLE.del',null,null,null);" > export.sql
        ij export.sql
        if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
                exit 1
        fi
done
```